# DenyEscalatingExec when under GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We're using GKE with our Kubernetes cluster. One of the apps we're running is Jenkins for CI. Unfortunately, Jenkins slaves need to use Docker to mount their host's `docker.sock`. This is, potentially, an escalation exploit.

The solution is to set up your Admission Controller in the API server to use `DenyEscalatingExec`. But I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to get at that setting through GKE. It could even be set by default, but I can't figure out how to even get at the default settings hidden behind GKE.

Is there a way to set this (and other controllers) through GKE, or otherwise check the defaults to see if it's set?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't change the enabled admission controllers on GKE. Alpha clusters support [external admission webhooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/extensible-admission-controllers) but that would involve an amount of custom work.

An alternative option would be to use PodSecurityPolicy to only allow privileged Pods to run in a few tightly controller namespaces. For example, you could create a jenkins namespace and only allow privileged Pods to be created in the jenkins and kube-system namespaces and then prevent all users but cluster admins from execing into Pods in those namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to run your Jenkins CI in a privileged mode. But if you just want to call Docker from inside a Jenkins, you don't need to use Privileged mode, you can just mount a Docker socket from the node to a Jenkins container.

```
spec:
      volumes:
      - name: docker-socket
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
      containers:
      - name: name
        image: image-location
        volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-socket
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Regarding Admission Controllers, all of them are provided by `kube-apiserver` binary and enabled on GKE.
[From the documentation about GKE:](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-security-policies)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-psp
spec:
  privileged: false  # Prevents creation of privileged Pods
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  volumes:
  - '*'
```

more examples you can find in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#example-policies)