# Enable PodTolerationRestriction on gcloud k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a namespace in k8s with the setting:
scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/defaultTolerations:
      '[{"key": "role_va", "operator": "Exists"}]'

If I am not mistaken all pods that are created in this namespace must get this toleration.
But the pods don't get it.
I read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#podtolerationrestriction) and understood that I must enable the PodTolerationRestriction controller.
How can I do this on gloud?

Answer (score 2):

In order to enable `PodTolerationRestriction` you might be required to set `--enable-admission-plugins` flag in `kube-apiserver` configuration. This is according to the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/), as by default this plugin is not included in admission controller plugins list.

However, in [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) there is no possibility to adapt any specific flag for the current API server run-time configuration, because Kubernetes cluster engine core components are not exposed to any user purpose actions (related Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451780/denyescalatingexec-when-under-gke)).

Assuming that, you can consider using [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-pl-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1003963&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_253508655583-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20EXA_M:1_PL_EN_Compute_Compute%20Engine_gce%20google-KWID_43700016289387310-kwd-79074734358-userloc_9067401&utm_term=KW_gce%20google-ST_gce%20google&ds_rl=1242853&ds_rl=1245734&ds_rl=1245734&gclid=CN_YhMegouECFTtTwgodRD8Img) and bootstrap cluster with any cluster building [solutions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/#local-machine-solutions), depending on your preference, within a particular GCE VM.